# Functioning for job crons and Python-crontab

Tags: python, linux, unix

guys. I am new on job crons and Python-crontab. Don't understand very well module , I created a simple testcron.py file with

```
from crontab import CronTab
cron = CronTab(user='root')
job = cron.new(command='echo hello_world')
job.minute.every(1)
cron.write()
```

I changed permision to 0774, and the execute as python3 testcron.py. Should I see every minute hello_world in my terminal? , because nothing happened.
I execute crontab -e and add path/testcron.py, but still i don't see "hello world"

Is missing the os library ?

Comment: Cron is weird. The jobs run, but not in a way that you can see the output. Try having the code write to a txt file or something. As far as i know, there is no way to "observe" code running executed from cron.

Comment: `I execute crontab -e and add path/testcron.py` Do you add a script for adding a script to cron to cron?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I see every minute hello_world in my terminal?

No.

> Is missing the os library ?

No.

Depending on your system configuration, the output *may* visible in your system logger. See `journalctl`.

Answer (score 0):

`Python-crontab` seems to be an interface for the system cron. If it works as advertised, your code should add a new command to the current cron (check with `crontab -l`). If no commands are added, you may not have sufficient rights (are you running as `root`?).

`Python-crontab` does not execute any scheduled tasks itself. I would recommend to get familiar with cron first, before using a programmatic interface.